# Can't see Macbook WiFi-access point on Android smartphone

Tags: macos, wifi, android

I'd like to connect my Android phone (Samsung Galaxy Nexus running Stock JellyBean) to my Macbook Pro (early-2012, running OSX Lion) via an access point created by my Macbook Pro.

Sadly I can't even see the access point on my Android phone.

Does anyone know a possible solution to this problem?

Additional information: A nearby Windows-PC and iPhone can connect to the AdHoc-network of the Macbook. The android phone can connect to all other wifi.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, most versions of Android do not support adhoc networking (only infrastructure), which is almost certainly what your Macbook is broadcasting. There is a program called Wifi Adhoc Enabler on the Play Store, which will allow the device to see adhoc networks. I think it requires root access though.

Comment: is it possible for osx to create a wifi access point, that android will support?